# How to check where in some other package/procedure my procedure(inside a package) is being used/referenced?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Say I have a package my_package with a procedure my_procedure in it.

I want to know from which other_procedures( in some other packages ) this procedure is being used/ called (for ex. from my_other_package.my_other_procedure)

Is this at all possible? If possible, how?

### Update 1:

I can use `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`, but the problem with `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` is it gives me the list of objects that uses `my_package` in general, and not the `my_procedure` in it. `my_package` has some 50 odd funtions and procedures, and a query to `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` for the package `my_package` gives me 30 odd results.

My database schema is huge, and querying ALL_SOURCES is taking ages.

### Update 2:

The following query, built up with the help of answers below, seems to be working good enough:

```
 select /*+  parallel(als, 16) */   * from all_source als 
 where type in ('PROCEDURE','PACKAGE BODY')
 and name in ( select NAME from all_Dependencies where referenced_name  = 'OE_HEADER_UTIL')
 and upper(text) like '%INSERT_ROW%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use view `ALL_SOURCE`, it contains source code of all stored procedures, and, better, `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`.

Comment: @Arnab I think it is due to concept "to hide implementation". You know your procedure depends on whole package, and you don't know implementation of package (you have not to depend on implementation). If your ALL_SOURCE view is too big, try to copy part of it with your package to another table and parse that copy.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (a bit complex but it works for my packages):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  l_own    VARCHAR2 (30) := 'YOUR_OWNER'; -- package owner
  l_obj    VARCHAR2 (30) := 'YOUR_PACKAGE'; -- package name
  l_priv   VARCHAR2 (30);
  l_cnt    NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Checking required privileges for [' || l_own || '.' || l_obj || ']');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TABLES and VIEWS');

  SELECT MAX (line)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM all_source
   WHERE owner = l_own AND name = l_obj AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY';

  IF l_cnt = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      'ERROR - Cannot read the [' || l_own || '.' || l_obj || '] package sources!');
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  FOR x IN (WITH txt AS
                   (SELECT line, UPPER (text) text, 'FROM\s*([_|\$|[:upper:]]+)' regexp
                      FROM all_source
                     WHERE owner = l_own AND name = l_obj AND REGEXP_INSTR (text, 'FROM\s*') > 0),
                 tabs AS
                   (SELECT line, text, tab
                      FROM (    SELECT line,
                                       text,
                                       REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (text,
                                                                                      regexp,
                                                                                      1,
                                                                                      LEVEL),
                                                                       '^FROM\s*'),
                                                       '^V\$',
                                                       'V_$')
                                         tab
                                  FROM txt
                            CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (text,
                                                      regexp,
                                                      1,
                                                      LEVEL)
                                         IS NOT NULL)
                     WHERE tab IS NOT NULL AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (tab, 'DUAL|TABLE')),
                 syns AS
                   (SELECT line,
                           text,
                           tab,
                           table_owner syn_own,
                           NVL (table_name, tab) syn_obj
                      FROM tabs INNER JOIN all_synonyms ON synonym_name(+) = tabs.tab),
                 syns_objs AS
                   (SELECT object_type typ, NVL (syn_own, owner) own, syn_obj obj
                      FROM syns INNER JOIN dba_objects ON syns.syn_obj = object_name)
              SELECT DISTINCT typ, own, obj
                FROM syns_objs
               WHERE typ <> 'SYNONYM'
            ORDER BY typ, own, obj) LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT DISTINCT privilege
        INTO l_priv
        FROM dba_tab_privs
       WHERE table_name = x.obj AND owner = x.own;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
    END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      RPAD ('. [' || x.typ || ']:' || x.own || '.' || x.obj, 80, ' ')||
      NVL (l_priv, 'NO_PRIVILEGE'));
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('PACKAGES');
  FOR x
    IN (  SELECT lvl,
                 object_type typ,
                 owner own,
                 object_name obj
            FROM (    SELECT LEVEL lvl, object_id
                        FROM public_dependency s
                  START WITH s.object_id =
                               (SELECT object_id
                                  FROM all_objects
                                 WHERE     owner = l_own
                                       AND object_name = l_obj
                                       AND object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY')
                  CONNECT BY s.object_id = PRIOR referenced_object_id
                    GROUP BY LEVEL, object_id) tree,
                 all_objects u
           WHERE tree.object_id = u.object_id AND u.owner <> 'PUBLIC'
        ORDER BY lvl) LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT DISTINCT privilege
        INTO l_priv
        FROM dba_tab_privs
       WHERE table_name = x.obj AND owner = x.own;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
    END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      RPAD (LPAD ('.', x.lvl, '.') || '[' || x.typ || ']:' || x.own || '.' || x.obj, 80, ' ')||
      NVL (l_priv, 'NO_PRIVILEGE'));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```